# Invalid Email Error Message Testing Chained Payments

Tags: paypal

I'm testing chained payments in the sandbox and no matter what email I put for the second recipient it tells me 'Invalid Request Parameter - email is invalid' - surely it doesn't matter what the email is in the sandbox??  Even though I have tried all my sandbox emails which I use to test other PayPal functions with regularly (and successfully).

My ActionType is PAY_PRIMARY (where payment to second recipient is delay).

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Here is full error message:

http://www.cybril.com/sitting/payment.php?id=9

Comment: Can you paste the complete response message received from the PayPal ?

Comment: Sorry Eshan I just saw your message - the complete response message is in the link above?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the account "verified". I saw that someone had that issue and it got resolved that way.